# How to randomly select between two variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How do you make a method to make Ruby select between two variables? For example say, I wanted Ruby to randomly output either "Dog" or "Cat"

Comment: Documentation: [Random](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Random.html).

Comment: You want to select between two *variables*? Or two strings?

Comment: It was two variables through the use of a method I'd call "random_name"

Answer (score 7):

You can easily use `sample` for this.

If you're working with an array:

```
myArray = ["Cat", "Dog", "Turtle"]
puts myArray.sample
```

If you want to choose between two variables:

```
cat = "Cat"
dog = "Dog"
puts [cat, dog].sample
```

You can read more about sample in the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sample)

Comment: Why the boolean array, when you can put the variables there directly?

Comment: So now, what's the difference between your two snippets? :)

Comment: Nothing, but based on the question op said he wanted to pick between two variables so I just wanted to show to create an array out of two variables (as opposed to just directly creating an array).

Comment: What if OP wants to sample n random elements?

Comment: @sagarpandya82: they don't :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you wanted to choose between two variables, here's what I think you mean:

```
dog = "Dog"
cat = "Cat"
[dog, cat].sample
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a ternary condition on a random number.

```
z = 'Milwaukee'
y = 'Chicago'
10.times {|x| puts rand(2) == 1 ? z : y}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use eval or [sample](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/sample) method of array, check out the following example.

```
arr = [dog="dog", cat="cat", turtle="turtle"]

## OUTPUT

2.2.1 :015 > dog
 => "dog" 
2.2.1 :016 > cat
 => "cat" 
2.2.1 :017 > turtle
 => "turtle"

## Using eval with sample

2.2.1 :018 > eval(arr.sample)
 => "dog" 
2.2.1 :019 > eval(arr.sample)
 => "cat" 
2.2.1 :020 > eval(arr.sample)
 => "turtle"

## OR (using sample)

2.2.1 :021 > arr.sample
 => "dog" 
2.2.1 :022 > arr.sample
 => "turtle" 
2.2.1 :023 > arr.sample
 => "cat"
```